# Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

This may be a duplicated question but rather than silencing the warning `Property 'Data' does not exist on type 'never'` I would actually like to understand why this warning is appearing and how I can fix it.

```
<template>
    ...
        <ion-content :fullscreen="true">
            <p v-if="!movieData">Loading...</p>
            <pre v-else>
        <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col size="6" :key="movie.Id" v-for="movie in movieData.Data.Movies"> <-- Warning appears here
                        <ion-img :src="movie.LargePosterUrl"></ion-img>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
      </pre>
        </ion-content>
    ...
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol, IonImg } from '@ionic/vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const movieData = ref(null);

const fetchData = async () => {
    movieData.value = null;
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://www.eventcinemas.com.au/Movies/GetNowShowing');
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
        }
        movieData.value = await res.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

fetchData();
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, here's the search I used to find the previous questions on this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvue.js%5D+ref+%5Btypescript%5D

Comment: You've opted to use TypeScript in your project, which you must understand is a strongly typed language.  Even though you've chosen _not_ to provide a type for `movieData`, types are not optional, so TS automatically infers the type based on the initial value, in your case `null` which is of type [never](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-never).  It is now always expected to be null. This is what it means to be strongly typed.  How can `movieData` possibly have a property called `Data` when it's null? If you define `movieData` with the proper type, you can avoid the error.

Comment: As I am rather new to Typescript interfaces, could you provide some guidance to creating an interface for `movieData`?